# Диалог выбора камеры при capDriverConnect (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, winapi, web-camera

Приложение делает снимки с камеры... При присоединении к окну камеры на некоторых ноутбуках появляется диалог выбора устройства записи. Это надо как-то пресечь. Решение, предложенное [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721085/webcam-video-source-dialog-comes-up) я протестировал и удалил из кода, так как оно почему-то не работает. На всякий случай вот код присоединения камеры:

```
// в WinMain
CamAvailable = FindCamDriver();
    if(CamAvailable){
        DWORD BindingThread;
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, BindCam, NULL, 0, &BindingThread);
    }
...

// Функции...
bool FindCamDriver(){
    while(!capGetDriverDescription(CamDeviceDriver, CamDeviceName, sizeof(CamDeviceName), CamDeviceVersion, sizeof(CamDeviceVersion))){
        if (++CamDeviceDriver > 9){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

DWORD WINAPI BindCam(LPVOID){
    while(!capDriverConnect(HStream, CamDeviceDriver)){
        continue;
    }
    ShowWindow(HStream, SW_SHOW);
    ShowWindow(FrameButton, SW_SHOW);
    return 0;
}
```

**Вопрос:** Как с бороться с этим диалоговым окном? Можно ли его как то перехватить и прибить до запуска, или где-то прописать, чтобы не выводилось? Если да, то как?

*Уточнение: приложение клиентское, должно запускаться и из под гостя, поэтому доступа к админским ключам реестра нет.*

PS: я знаю, vfw - технология устаревшая, но с DirectShow MinGW не дружит, а статические линки с ffmpeg или opencv до неприличия раздуют исполняемый файл, да и собирать их для gcc головная боль.

Comment: Можно прибить "хакерским" способом, поставив хук в отдельном thread на создание окон, спросив класс окна, и прибивать окно, скрыв его видимость и кликая на ОК, а легально как  - хороший вопрос.

Comment: Неважно каким способом, главное без админских привилегий. Я обнаружил, что если в диспетчере задач перейти от приложения выбора видеоустройста к его процессу, то это будет мой процесс! То есть мне надо как-то получить хэлнд этого окна и сразу его прибить. А как этот хэндл получить?

Comment: Хук на [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583493/cbt-createwnd-structure-has-invalid-name/20584011#20584011) и [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) c WH_CBT в параметр